# How to transfer values from controller to view codeigniter into dropdownlist

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
  if (is_array($jsonhome)) {
                foreach ($jsonhome as $query) {
                    foreach ($query['results']['place'] as $places) {


                        if (is_array($places['country'])) {
                            echo "Country:\n";
                            echo "Content: " . $places['country']['content'] . "\n\n";
                        }

                        if (is_array($places['admin1'])) {
                            echo "State:\n";
                            echo "Content: " . $places['admin1']['content'] . "\n\n";
                        }

                        if (is_array($places['admin2'])) {
                            echo "District/City:\n";
                            echo "Content: " . $places['admin2']['content'] . "\n\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    $location_data['user_current_country'] = $places['country']['content'];

            $this->load->view('header_register', $location_data);
            $this->load->view('body_complete_register', $location_data);
            $this->load->view('footer_register');
```

I want to transfer the country to input type select in the view codeigniter:

Say i get two countries via the above queries say India and USA i want to pass it to the view

Do i do it via ajax?

Please help i am new to codeigniter

Comment: Is this view code or controller? where is the code to load view?

Comment: you have to place above code in your view. `$places['country']['content']` will return only last record.

Comment: Do i pass the whole $jsonhome to view?

Comment: Yes. You have to pass it to view and do above code in view instead of controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So **in your controller** you want to build an array of options for your `<select>`.  Something like

```
//Build array of country options
$aData['countryOptions'] = array();
foreach ($jsonhome as $query) {
    foreach ($query['results']['place'] as $places) {
        $aData['countryOptions'][] = $places['country']['content'];
    }
}

$this->load->view('body_complete_register', $aData);
```

Then **in your view** you can use the `form_dropdown` function providing you have the form helper loaded

```
$this->load->helper('form');
echo form_dropdown('countries', $countryOptions);
```

Of if you don't want to use the helper you could do

```
<select name="countries" id="countries">
    <?php foreach($countryOptions as $key => $countryName) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $countryName ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**Please note** that you shouldn't be echoing anything out in the controller.  The controller is just for passing data between models, libraries and views